# Can't click to see spoiler tags

Tags: bug, status-norepro, spoilers

I have cleared cookies, logged out and back in, and disabled ublock origin. I have no other add-ons. Running latest version of Firefox. It works in chrome and edge with ublock running. Driving me crazy having to edit the answers just to see what they are.

Additionally, spoiler tags on other Stack Exchange sites work normally.

Spoiler tags on other exchanges look like this in my browser:

[image: regular gray spoiler block with "Reveal spoiler" shown in the corner]

Spoiler tags on the Puzzling exchange look like this:

[image: smaller gray box with no "Reveal spoiler" in the corner]

Comment: Is this broken cross-site? For example, can you see the contents of this spoiler? https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/21738/11259

Comment: Good idea, oddly enough that spoiler tag works normally for me. Another tidbit, the literature spoiler tag has text that says "reveal spoiler !" whereas the ones on the puzzling exchange are just an empty quote box.

Comment: Could you check this spoiler as well? https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/253060 Testing one more theory: perhaps it's broken only on sites with custom designs, like Puzzling and Sci Fi, but not Literature

Comment: Works on the scifi as well.

Comment: Weird. I've tried recruiting other people in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/60432039#60432039) with Firefox to repro this

Comment: I actually disabled all add-ons, there were some I didn't realize were running and it fixed the problem. It was an obscure no longer used or updated add-on. Issue resolved.

Comment: I'm closing this because the person who posted it has indicated that it was caused by a browser addon misbehaving.

Comment: (This makes it look as if it's been declared off-topic, which isn't really fair, but that's a deficiency of the way that closed questions show up here.)

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan, wouldn't it be better for ACD to post his comment as an answer and then accept it?  Then this will properly look like an answered question rather than an inappropriate one.

Comment: That would also have been an option. Dunno whether it would have been _better_; that depends on whether it's common for people to have this problem because of a misbehaving browser addon. My guess is not.